# Script Time Exceeded in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is the first time I am programming using Google Script and I cannot figure out how to add a function to circumvent Google's error message of exceeding processing time. Could you please help?

The program gets the number of bars and pints ordered and references them into a different sheet which has a calculator to calculate costs and outputs the value. Would really appreciate the help

```
/**
 * 
 *
 */

function STBIBOL()
{

  var r = 6
  var destclm = 11
  var pintsclm = 105
  var barsclm = 101

  var spreadsheet_url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cqgdo_pgJ4n0xhXqMah24g6jjv7sfl2o92k1pwXNUuo/edit#gid=532254312';
  var sheet_name = 'BOLs Entered for Fulfillment';
  var sheet_name1 = 'STBI Calculator';

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheet_url);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheet_name);
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName(sheet_name1);
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  for(i =1; i< 20; i++)
  {
    var rangeD = sheet.getRange(r,destclm)
    var dest = rangeD.getValue()
    var rangeS = sheet.getRange(r,pintsclm)
    var pints = rangeS.getValue()
    var rangeB = sheet.getRange(r, barsclm)
    var bars = rangeB.getValue()
    var range = sheet1.getRange(14,3)
    range.setValue(dest)
    var range2 = sheet1.getRange(11, 3)
    range2.setValue(pints)
    var range3 = sheet1.getRange(12, 3)
    range3.setValue(bars)
    var rangev = sheet1.getRange(8,3)
    var value = rangev.getValue()
    var range4 = sheet.getRange(r,110)
    range4.setValue(value)    
    r = r + 1
   }


}
```

Comment: EDIT: The For loop should eventually be for (i =1; i<lastRow; i++) when I figure out the time

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Jeet Ghosh.  Would it be easier (and faster execution) to simply code the logic in your script rather than accessing a spreadsheet?  Have you tested this with a simplified version of your script?

Comment: No I haven't. I'm not the most fluent in Javascript and unfortunately something at work needs to be resolved and while I intend to take classes, I was trying to find an effective solution. Pretty sure I have hit one. I can post the updated code when i am ready

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making multiple calls to GAS services on each run of the loop, which causes the execution to fail, you could simply get the entire range in one call like this:

```
 var range1 = sheet1.getRange(startRow, startColumn, numberOfRows, numberOfColumns);
```

If the range in the 2nd sheet has the same dimensions (same number of rows and columns) as the 1st sheet, you could simply 1) get the values from the original sheet as a 2d array

```
var values1 = range.getValues();
```

2) Write values to the 2nd sheet

```
var range2 = sheet2.getRange(startRow, startColumn, numberOfRows, numberOfColumns);
range2.setValues(values1);
```

Comment: How would I then get the individual values from the entire range?

Comment: You iterate over the array using the the basic 'for' loop. I suggest you find a beginner JavaScript course before going any further with Google Apps Script